Fastest growing renewal process
There is a lemma in my lecture notes stating that the renewal function $m(t)=\mathbb{E}[X_t]$, of a renewal process $X_t$ with inter-arrival density $f$, satisfies the upper bound:
$$m(t)\le Ce^t \text{ for some }C>0$$
Poisson processes of rate $\lambda$, as we know, satisfy $m(t)=\lambda t$ and have linear growth in $m(t)$. The elementary renewal theorem, $\lim \limits_{t \to \infty}{\frac{m(t)}{t}}=\frac{1}{\mu}$ (where $\mu$ is the inter-arrival distribution's expectation) seems to suggest that all renewal processes have $m(t)$ asymptotically linear in $t$.
Is this correct and the inequality in my notes a slack upper bound, or is it possible for a renewal process to grow exponentially? Which inter-arrival distribution leads to the fastest growing renewal process?

The exponential bound is rather slack.
Suppose your renewal process has interarrival times $T_1, T_2,\ldots$. Fix $c>0$ and truncate to $T_k^{(c)}:=T_k\wedge c$. This results in a renewal process with more rapid renewal, hence a larger renewal function:
$$
m(t)\le m^{(c)}(t).
$$
But by Wald's identity
$$
E\left(S^{(c)}_{X^{(c)}_t+1}\right)=(m^{(c)}(t)+1)\mu^{(c)},
$$
where $S^{(c)}_n=T^{(c)}_1+\cdots T^{(c)}_n$ and $\mu^{(c)}:=E(T^{(c)}_1)$.
A picture makes it clear that $S^{(c)}_{X^{(c)}_t+1}\le t+c$.
Thus
$$
m(t)\le m^{(c)}(t)=E\left(S^{(c)}_{X^{(c)}_t+1}\right)/\mu^{(c)}-1\le {t+c\over\mu^{(c)}}-1.
$$

That's much more useful, thanks. Not sure why we weren't given this bound instead.

I learned this "trick" in Durrett's book (if I remember correctly...).
